# Complement operator ~ in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
        int a = 11; // 0000 0000 0000 1011
        int b = ~a; // 1111 1111 1111 0101 [2s compliment] 0100 => 0101 => 
        printf("\n %d \n",b); // -11
        return 0;
}
```

This program outputs the value -12. Assuming the "~" corresponds to 2's compliement it has to output -11, if its 1's compliment it has to output -4.
Couldnt get how it outputs the value 12.

Comment: doesn't ~ just flip each bit so that 1011 become 0100?

Comment: To search questions about operators you do not know the name, use `"~"` as search string!

Answer (score 2):

The `~` operator is not 2's complement, but bitwise negation. It just changes every bit.

2's compliment is defined as `(~a)+1`.